# Translation of artist signature

Tags: translation

Can someone translate this artists name please?  Thank you in advance.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3mLF.jpg)

Comment: it's kanji, "野島青茲" is a japanese. maybe, you can grep more info in japanese stackexchange https://japanese.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Handwriting: 青兹
Seal: 兹

[青](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%9D%92) has a lot of meanings. For example, blue, young, east, or grass.

[兹](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%85%B9), [玆](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%8E%86) and [茲](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%8C%B2) are variants.
兹 may mean black or dirty.
茲 means this, now or year.